# Properties of bounded, continuous process $(X_t)$ if $(\mathrm{e}^{t/2} X_t)$ is a martingale.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

Consider two complex stochastic processes $(X_t)_{t\ge 0}$ and $(Y_t)_{t\ge 0}$ (adapted to a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\ge 0}$) with the following properties:
$$
\begin{align}
(1)& \ (X_t) \text{ is continuous.}\\
(2)& \ M_t := \mathrm{e}^{t/2} X_t \text{ is a martingale (w.r.t. $(\mathcal{F}_t)$).}\\
(3)& \ |X_t| \le 1 \; \forall t\ge 0.\\
(4)& \ X_0 = 1.
\end{align}
$$
The process $(Y_t)$ has the same properties except that $Y_0 = 0$. What I wish to find is something about the long-term behaviour of $|X_t|$ and $|Y_t|$. My conjecture is that $X_t = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} B_t}$ for a Brownian motion $(B_t)$ and $Y_t = 0 \, \forall t\ge 0$, but I have not been able to deduce any of the two (Actually, knowing that $|X_t| = 1 \forall t \ge 0$ would be enough for my purposes).

One of the corollaries I was able to make is that, since $|M_t|$ and thereby $|M_t|^2$ are sub-martingales,
$ \mathbb{E}  |X_t|^2 \ge \mathrm{e}^{-t},$
but that is not very interesting for large $t$.

I would very much appreciate any hint at interesting properties that follow from the above or any further conditions that would, in conjunction with the properties above, be sufficient to imply my conjecture.

Comment: I don't think you have enough hypotheses for your conjecture about $Y_t$, at least.  If I let $W_t$ be complex Brownian motion started at 0, and $\tau = \inf\{t : |W_t| = e^{t/2}\}$, then $Y_t := e^{-t/2} W_{t \wedge \tau}$ satisfies all the hypotheses.  Still not sure about $X_t$.

Comment: Actually, doesn't $X_t = e^{-t/2}$ satisfy all your hypotheses for $X_t$?

Comment: @NateEldredge Right, thank you!

Do you have any idea what further assumptions would be necessary to show one of my conjectures? I know there are some martingale characterisations of Brownian motion, but all of them seem to contain some kind of assumption on $B_t^2$, not $\exp(\mathrm{i}B_t)$